# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook --> 800700c1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I "own" a C# WinForms Desktop app that has about 30-50 users using it per day (usually constantly during their shifts).  One of the things it does is call Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and/or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in order to open up a new Word or Outlook document and then populate that document with information.  The user then can manually override before either saving the Word doc or sending the email.

For ONE user, it seems that he suddenly is no longer able to get the app to open up a new Outlook message. It's throwing an exception:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).

And it's referencing the line where we do:
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();

I've been Googling for a few hours on this, trying to figure out "why just this one user?" and how to fix it.  I had him run the Office 365's "Online Repair" feature.   I had him try re-registering the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll file.  No change.  I found some articles out there that suggested if one's project is set to a build platform target of "Any CPU", that can cause the problem.  So I created a special version just for this user where it was set to "x86" (as per the recommendation).  No change. (Meanwhile, by the way, the app can hand off to Word no problem!)

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do next to try to fix this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is using the version that you've referenced? Also check that he has Outlook installed. Then check that he can open Outlook without any pop-up messages when it's opened.

Comment: You are likely going to end up walking through all the COM registration for Word on two machines, one that works and the one that fails. I really don't miss COM at all

Comment: Are you sure that the user has 32-bit Outlook installed? According to the following post: https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/retrieving-com-class-factory-for-component-failed-800700c1/ error 800700C1 could be a "bitness" issue. According to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261, "The 64-bit version of Office is automatically installed unless you explicitly select the 32-bit version before beginning the installation process"

Comment: Yes, Outlook is installed. He uses it all day long.  We're in a corporate environment and corporate manages the installation and auto-updating of these laptops. I would think we'd all be using 64-bit version.  In Programs, we don't actually show Word or Outlook.  Just "Microsoft Apps for enterprise -en-us".     However, on my own laptop, if I trace my shortcuts for Word and Outlook, they're in C:\Program_Files(x86).   But for him, they're in C:\Program Files\    Path otherwise matches (Microsoft Office\root\Office16\).

Comment: When I said "In Programs" with my last comment, I'm referring to "Control Panel" -> "Programs"

Comment: @user9938  Yes, I'd found that post yesterday.  I've already tried publishing to this user only a version of my project where instead of the platform target being "Any CPU", it was set to "x86".  He installed it.  Tried it.  Still gets the exception.

Comment: If Outlook is 64-bit, try compiling your program as 64-bit. You can use `dumpbin.exe <filename> | find /i "machine"` to display the "bitness" of the.exe files

Comment: @user9938  Yes, it was set to 32-bit. I recompiled as 64-bit. Had user install it. Not only does he still get the same Exception when handing off to Outlook, now handing off to Word (which previously worked) gives an "800700c1 / is not a valid Win32 application" exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, my user decided to go make sure he was updated to the latest version of Windows 10.  (Despite the fact that corporate has managed each device's Windows Updates for years now.)

But doing this solved the issue.  It was indeed an OS installation issue.